# Monitor requests made by Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to monitor all the requests made by a Chrome extension, in the same way that the Network panel monitors all the requests made by a page?

Comment: I would guess that Process Monitor from Sysinternals could be a good place to start, though I'm not sure how you could tag the extension data to separate it from the Chrome data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may monitor an extension in Google Chrome by :

1. Open Settings
2. Click on Extensions
3. Check Developer mode, which will change the display :
   [image: image1]
4. Click on the link next to "Inspect views" of the extension
5. A Developer Tools window will open up for your extension with which you can
   monitor the extension.
   [image: image2]